# How to check if element in array contains any values from a list Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, contains

I have a list of words:

```
list1 = ['foo', 'baz', 'bat']
```

And an array of strings:

```
list2 = ['foo word word word', 'word baz word word', 'word word word word', 'word word bat word']
string_arr = np.array(list2)
```

I want to enumerate through the array and return a boolean if the element in the array contains any of the values in the list. The output to be a list of booleans:

```
[True, True, False, True]
```

Right now all I have is this code which just gives me a list of indices, which I don't want:

```
idx_mask = [idx for idx, element in enumerate(string_arr) if any(x in element for x in list1)]
```

How can I just get a list of booleans?

Comment: Do you want the text to contain a substring or specifically a word? if `list1` contains `w`, should result be `True` on all of them?

Comment: @MikeB No, only if it contains the full word, the answer below works

Comment: Making `list2` an array does not gain you anything.  It's faster to iterate through  a list, and `numpy` does not implement any special, faster, string methods.

Comment: @5sWithCrackScreen - no it doesn't. It works only for this example. Add 'w' to the list1 and all answers will be `True`

Comment: @MikeB Yes, but I'm only looking for like words in my case. Basically the SQL equivalent of like '%foo%

Comment: @hpaulj I know, what I'm working on requires np arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find only full word matches, you should match them to each string from `list2` split by space to make a word array:

```
print([any(x in element.split(' ') for x in list1) for element in list2])
```

Test:

```
list1 = ['foo', 'baz', 'bat', 'w']
list2 = ['foo word word word', 'word baz word word', 'word word word word', 'word word bat word']
```

results are: 
`[True, True, False, True]`  
which is the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

```
print([any(x in element for x in list1) for element in list2])
```